# Why Comparable protocol does not have default implementation of Equatable?

Tags: swift

Why swift doesn't have a built-in implementation of Equatable for Comparable protocol like this?

```
extension Comparable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return !(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fogmeister The `Comparable` protocol requires that exactly one of `a == b`, `a < b` or `b < a` is true for any `a` and `b` so if you're implementing `Comparable` properly, yes, they would have to be the same person (or your `<` implementation has to look at more than just height).

Comment: @dan ah. Didn’t know that. Thanks :-)

Comment: @dan Unless one of the values is "exceptional." (Which has got to be the greatest dodge I've seen in a spec in a long time… This rule applies everywhere except where it doesn't.) "For example, the special “not a number” value for floating-point types (FloatingPoint.nan) compares as neither less than, greater than, nor equal to any normal floating-point value."

Comment: Since the compiler can synthesise `==` if all properties conforms to Equatable a default built-in implementation would then mean 2 `==` implementations, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in comments thanks all:

Assuming `a<b` is false and `b<a` is false then `a==b`, is not correct for special cases like `Float.nan` according to documentation:

> A NaN compares not equal, not greater than, and not less than every
>   value, including itself. Passing a NaN to an operation generally
>   results in NaN.